# Number usage in a series

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, numbers

Is it right to say that the percentage decreases by 10% each time, like in this example:

> Around 30% of politicians throughout the world are women. A significant 30% is represented in Scandinavian nations in which it decreases by 10% each time in both Asia and Latin America, respectively.

How do we say each time in a report?

Comment: What are you trying to say? It is 30% in Scandinavian countries, 20% in Asia and 10% in Latin America?

Comment: yeah, but sorry the first percentage i meant was 10 not 30% of politicians

Comment: It would be much clearer to just give the numbers for each category, as Preetie says.

Answer (score 2):

No.

When you say that the percentage of women politicians decrease by 10% (from 30% in Scandinavia to Asia), it means that the percentage of women politicians in Asia is (1 - 10%) * 30% = 27%.

Going from 30% to 20% is a decrease of 33.33%.

You can rephrase by saying that,

> Scandinavia has a significant female representation in politics with 30% female politicians. However, this figure is only 20% for Asia and 10% for Latin America.

Answer (score 1):

The term *percentage point* is commonly used to reduce ambiguity when percentages are discussed.

If 30 percent of Scandinavian politicians are women and 20 percent of Asian politicians are women, then the share of politicians who are women is:

- 10 *percentage points* higher in Scandinavia than in Asia
- 50 *percent* higher in Scandinavia than in Asia
- 150 percent *as high* in Scandinavia as in Asia

As commenters have noted, your "decreases by 10% each time" language is not common, requires readers/listeners to do too much work in their heads, and should be avoided.